# how can I perform operation which is defined in a character array?

Tags: c

I have taken a character array of certain operators. Each time it gets an operator I want to perform the operation using that operator. How can I do that?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *c = "+-*/" ;
    int a = 10 , b = 5 ;
    for(int i = 0 ; c[i]!='\0';i++){
        int z = a c[i] b ; 
        printf("%d ",z) ; 
    }
}
```

expected output : `15 5 50 2`

Comment: You need to write a function that performs the correct operation depending on the inputs

Comment: `int z = a c[i] b ;` does not do what you think it is doing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I guess we take that line as pseudocode for "please fix me"

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to move logic to a separate function and  switch char to select action

```
#include<stdio.h>

int errCode = -999876; // magic error code exmpl

int useArithm(char c, int a, int b) {
    switch (c) {
        case '+' : {
            return a + b;
        }
        break;
        case '-' : {
            return a - b;
        }
        break;
        case '*' : {
            return a * b;
        }
        break;
        case '/' : {
            if (b == 0) {
                // bed b msg ;)
                return errCode;
            }
            return a / b;
        }
        break;
    }
    return errCode;
}

int main() {
    char *c = "+-*/" ;
    int a = 10 , b = 5 ;
    for (int i = 0; c[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        if (c[i] == '+' || c[i] == '-' || c[i] == '*' || c[i] == '/') {
            int z = useArithm(c[i], a, b); 
            if (z == errCode) {
                // error action
            }
            printf("%d ",z) ; 
        } else {
            // error msg
            break;
        }

    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Magic error code is a bad idea (though I like the rest). Use a `default:` case and `exit {EXIT_FAILURE};` from there. Since the function returns `int`, returning some `int` as an error-code is a no-go. (but still worth the UV)

Comment: @David C. Rankin Yes, but the question was about the logic of operator definition. The topic of error code retrieval is great for discussion in this topic. And i select it's only exmpl ;)

Comment: Agreed, that's why I overlooked it and still gave your answer the nod, but it does deserve a comment in light of the function return type. Ideally the operator checking of the array contents would be done before passing to the function to eliminate this sticky situation.

Comment: `b` should not be zero.

Comment: @Biswapriyo - fix it)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this (in the loop)

```
if (c[i] == '+' )
{
// do the plus operation.
}
else if ( c[i] == '-') 
{
// do the minus operation.
}
/// ... same thing for the other operations.
```

Comment: I know i can do this ...but this is so lengthy .It will be helpful if  there is any other way to do so

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing built in.

A case statement will be slightly briefer than the if/else logic, but not if you factor in the break statements.

Another option would be a function map. In C++, something like (note this is uncompiled thought code):

```
typedef int (*binop)(int a,int b);
std::map<char, binop> operations
{ { '+', [](int a, int b)->int { return a+b;} },
  { '-', [](int a, int b)->int { return a-b;} }
};

...

auto  op = operations[c[i]];
if (op) return op(a,b);

... or the more devilish:

operations.insert(c[i], [](int a, int b)->int { throw NoOpException();}).first(a,b);
```

But to implement a map and populate it in C and declare all the little worker functions would be so much bloat code!

Comment: This question is tagged `[c]`. Please avoid `[c++]` answers. Perhaps a comparison of the C `switch` source code and C++ `map` source is prudent before commenting on "bloat code".

Comment: yah i know about this .That's why I am confused is there anything in c also to easily do that !!

Comment: My point was that to implement a map and an exception engine in C would be so much bloat code, not the comparison with the case statement.

Comment: Yes, that is a valid point, it would look like the C++ source for `map` and the source for the exception handling.

Comment: No, it would be worse than that, as you get no object wrappers, so everything would need 5 mile long names, etc. This is why C++